# How to show the parent task in a task list view?

Tags: task-list

I have synced a Project with Sharepoint using the [Project 2010 blog instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/project/project-2010-introducing-sync-to-sharepoint). This way I can create the tasks in Project and they appear automatically in a webpart where I put a view of the tasks, sorted by date and configured to show all the items without folders. Then a user will have the next tasks he has to do in the main sharepoint page.

The problem we have now is that the tasks view shows the task name, but we want to show the name of the parent "folder", because our projects' have many levels and some tasks name are not descriptive enough.

Is it possible to modify the list or the view to allow us showing at least one parent level in the list? Something like:

```
Title         Status    Priority    Due Date    %Complete    Parent Task
```

Comment: I would like to do this too - did you ever come up with a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It's a pity you can't use a calculated column to show the FileLeafRef or something.

The only other way i can think of; is using an event receiver on the list ItemAdd/ItemUpdate, to set the column.